# Why using one item array with CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS not working?

Tags: php, curl

Is there an explanation why using array gave me 500 internal server error and using string just works fine with same input ?

```
    $header_array[] = 'Host: example.com';
    $header_array[] = 'Accept-Language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3';
 //   $header_array[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate';
    $header_array[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
    $header_array[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';
    $header_array[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
    $header_array[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
    $header_array[] = 'Referer: https://example.com/post/'.$post_id;
    $header_array[] = 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest';
    $header_array[] = 'Content-Length: '.strlen("id=".$post_id);
    /* curl */
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header_array);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
```

not working (internal server error):

```
    $post_array['id'] = "1";
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_array);
```

working:

```
    $post_string = "id=1";
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_string);
```

this is also working on another url:

```
    $post_array['__Token'] = $token;
    $post_array['UserName'] = $this->username;
    $post_array['Password'] = $this->password;
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_array);
```

curl verbose output of error:

```
Array
(
    [url] => https://example.com/post/delete
    [content_type] => 
    [http_code] => 500
    [header_size] => 257
    [request_size] => 879
    [filetime] => -1
    [ssl_verify_result] => 0
    [redirect_count] => 0
    [total_time] => 0.370037
    [namelookup_time] => 2.7E-5
    [connect_time] => 0.109487
    [pretransfer_time] => 0.187462
    [size_upload] => 145
    [size_download] => 0
    [speed_download] => 0
    [speed_upload] => 391
    [download_content_length] => 0
    [upload_content_length] => 145
    [starttransfer_time] => 0.335593
    [redirect_time] => 0
    [redirect_url] => 
    [primary_ip] => 188.132.xx.xxx
    [certinfo] => Array
        (
        )

    [primary_port] => 443
    [local_ip] => 172.20.xx.xxx
    [local_port] => 63696
)
```

my phpinfo states:

```
Core

PHP Version => 5.5.14
curl

cURL support => enabled
cURL Information => 7.37.1
```

Comment: *not working* is not a usefull problem description

Comment: @Dagon i've added not working description on my question as 500 internal server error. I hope this is useful for you ?

Comment: I think you're supposed to use [`http_build_query()`](https://php.net/http_build_query) on the array you want to send with `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS`, e.g. `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, http_build_query($post_array));`

Comment: @scrowler and why it does work without using it on last example ?

Comment: Well in your last example the `$post_string` doesn't represent the `$post_array` values above it so most of that example is irrelevant

Comment: @scrowler just a simple copy paste mistake fixed. yes it's relevant of course.

Comment: When you receive an internal server error the reason should be logged in the server's error log. What does it say?

Comment: Is `$post_array` ever actually initialized as an array?

Comment: Have you looked in the Apache log file for the actual error message for the general 500 error status?

Comment: @AdamChysky unfortunately at the moment i don't have access to server log but anyway both as string post or as an array post it has to be work! i am suspecting this could be a php-curl implementation bug may be.

Comment: @Sammitch before using it in post i just use print_r($post_array) and this is the output:

Array
(
    [id] => 44513191
) seems pretty proper.

Comment: Even if you can't access the log to identify the 500, you can enable display_errors in your code. At the top: `error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` Unless it's a parse error, this should cause it to be displayed.

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski i'm not sure if that's usefeul but i've added curl verbose output of the error and the page states 500 internal server error. i think the point is may be something wrong with php version or curl implementation.

Comment: @scrowler it works with http_build_query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take a look at  PHP manual, it says:

> Passing an array to CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS will encode the data as
>   multipart/form-data, while passing a URL-encoded string will encode
>   the data as application/x-www-form-urlencoded.

And you have these lines in your code:

```
$header_array[] = 'Content-Length: '.strlen("id=".$post_id);
$header_array[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
```

if you remove those lines, it will be ok!

---

My code currently looks like this:

```
<?php 
    //$header_array[] = 'Host: example.com';

    //$header_array[] = 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate';
    $header_array[] = 'Accept-Language: tr-TR,tr;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.5,en;q=0.3';
    $header_array[] = 'Connection: keep-alive';
    $header_array[] = 'Cache-Control: no-cache';

    $header_array[] = 'Pragma: no-cache';
    $header_array[] = 'Referer: https://example.com/post/'.$post_id;
    $header_array[] = 'X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest';
    //$header_array[] = 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8';
    //$header_array[] = 'Content-Length: '.strlen("id=".$post_id);
    /* curl */

    $ch = curl_init('http://example.com/your/file.php');

    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header_array);
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, TRUE);
    $post_array['id'] = "1";
    curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_array);


    $data = curl_exec($ch);
?>
```

If it shows the same error, try adding :

```
$header_array[] = 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked';
```

Comment: actually i get this error: "HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length." and after adding content-length again it doesn't worked either. Seems like there is no way to use array when it's not "multipart/form-data"

Comment: sorry, still same error "HTTP Error 411. The request must be chunked or have a content length."

Comment: @motto did you try the last line ?

Comment: still no luck. same 500 internal error on this time. i decided to use "http_build_query($post_array)"